# Can not edit rdl report (2005 defination) in Vs 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, report, reportingservices-2005, rdl

I have a rdl report with 2005 defination, If I try to edit in VS2008 or Report Builder 2.0 I get an error like below ;

Have any idea, how I can edit this report without harm it.

Thanks

Sefer

```
> Deserialization failed: The element 'Field' in namespace
> 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition'
> has invalid child element 'TypeName' in namespace
> 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition'.
> List of possible elements expected: 'DataField, Value' in namespace
> 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition'
> as well as any element in namespace '##other'. Line 465, position 12.
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your choices are 1) upgrade the report to 2008 or 2) Download VS 2005 to work on it.

Comment: When you open the file in VS2008 does it prompt you to upgrade the file?

Comment: Unfortunately vs2008 does not ask upgrade

Comment: You will have to use an older version of Visual Studio to work on it, as Tab Alleman mentioned.

Comment: Are you using VS or report builder to modify the report?  Report builder will not upgrade a report but VS can.

Comment: You can also just edit the report in any text editor since rdls are simply xml files.

Comment: Rdl file 10k row, it is not easy work with text or xml editor. Thanks for your advices

Comment: I find a 3th party RDL designer name fyireporting. You can design all 2005 defination RDl files. http://www.fyireporting.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many users have said, your options are to either use Visual Studio 2005, or upgrade the SSIS package.  If you are not getting prompted to do so, try the steps in this link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/03/21/package-upgrade-wizard.aspx

Also, be mindful of what version of integration services is running on your server.  If you're running 2005, you'll probably want to just use VS2005...otherwise if you're running 2008, then I'd suggest upgrading the package.