# C# Winform – Extending solution working for single DataSet to Multiple DataSets for ReportViewer Reports with the help of RDL file

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset, report, rdl

I had this code taken from [Reza Aghaei’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40395159/c-sharp-winform-how-to-display-real-time-reports-by-passing-3-variables-to-rep), which had helped me solve the problem for single DataSet using Microsofts Reportviewer Control on Winforms.

### **Working Part:**

**Calling Form:**

```
string sql = "SELECT bk_book_details.id, bk_book_details.book_id, bk_book_details.book_no, bk_book_details.book_name, bk_book_details.edition_id, bk_book_details.condition_id, bk_book_details.publication_year, bk_book_details.price, bk_book_details.purchase_price, bk_book_details.reference_no, bk_book_details.book_status, bk_book_details.purchase_id, bk_book_details.purchase_date FROM bk_book_details";
string reportLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Reports\LMS_Book_Price_Invoice.rdl";
var f = new ReportForm();
f.ReportPath = reportLocation;
DataTable dt = (DataTable)DataAdapter.Current.LoadData(sql, "LoadDataTable");
List<DataTable> lDt = new List<DataTable>();
lDt.Add(dt);
f.ReportData = new List<DataTable>(lDt);
f.ShowDialog();
```

**Report Form:**

```
public List<DataTable> ReportData { get; set; }
public string ReportPath { get; set; }

private void ReportForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    long numberOfDataSets = this.ReportData.Count();
    if (numberOfDataSets == 0)
        return;

    var rds = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("Data", this.ReportData[i]);
    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

    reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = this.ReportPath;
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

Which I extended to take multiple DataSets like so:

1. Added the same SQL statement 3 times with addition of where
   condition to 3 tables added to the RDL file with 3 separate DataSets
   namely: Data, Data1, Data2

### **code after modification:**

**Calling Form:**

```
        string sql = "SELECT bk_book_details.id, bk_book_details.book_id, bk_book_details.book_no, bk_book_details.book_name, bk_book_details.edition_id, bk_book_details.condition_id, bk_book_details.publication_year, bk_book_details.price, bk_book_details.purchase_price, bk_book_details.reference_no, bk_book_details.book_status, bk_book_details.purchase_id, bk_book_details.purchase_date FROM bk_book_details WHERE bk_book_details.book_id<=2";
        string sql1 = "SELECT bk_book_details.id, bk_book_details.book_id, bk_book_details.book_no, bk_book_details.book_name, bk_book_details.edition_id, bk_book_details.condition_id, bk_book_details.publication_year, bk_book_details.price, bk_book_details.purchase_price, bk_book_details.reference_no, bk_book_details.book_status, bk_book_details.purchase_id, bk_book_details.purchase_date FROM bk_book_details WHERE bk_book_details.book_id=4";
        string sql2 = "SELECT bk_book_details.id, bk_book_details.book_id, bk_book_details.book_no, bk_book_details.book_name, bk_book_details.edition_id, bk_book_details.condition_id, bk_book_details.publication_year, bk_book_details.price, bk_book_details.purchase_price, bk_book_details.reference_no, bk_book_details.book_status, bk_book_details.purchase_id, bk_book_details.purchase_date FROM bk_book_details WHERE bk_book_details.book_id=5";

        string reportLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Reports\LMS_Book_Price_Invoice_2.rdl";

        var f = new ReportForm();
        f.ReportPath = reportLocation;
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)DataAdapter.Current.LoadData(sql, "LoadDataTable");
        DataTable dt1 = (DataTable)DataAdapter.Current.LoadData(sql1, "LoadDataTable1");
        DataTable dt2 = (DataTable)DataAdapter.Current.LoadData(sql2, "LoadDataTable2");

        List<DataTable> lDt = new List<DataTable>();
        lDt.Add(dt);
        lDt.Add(dt1);
        lDt.Add(dt2); 
        f.ReportData = new List<DataTable>(lDt);
        f.ShowDialog();
```

**Report Form:**

```
    public List<DataTable> ReportData { get; set; }
    public string ReportPath { get; set; }

    private void ReportForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        long numberOfDataSets = this.ReportData.Count();
        if (numberOfDataSets == 0)
            return;

        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        string dataX = "Data";
        for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfDataSets; i++) {
            string DataName = dataX;
            if (i != 0)
                DataName += Convert.ToString(i);
            /*For our case the DataName is used to provide DataSet name Data, Data1, Data2*/

            var rds = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource(DataName, this.ReportData[i]);
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        }
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = this.ReportPath;
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

After this, the code continues to work for Single DataSet like so:
[image]

However for Multiple Datasets, it gives the following error:
[image]

**Search results:**

1. When I looked for this error, I got this SO link where I don’t know
   why the same error occurs:

[Can not edit rdl report (2005 defination) in Vs 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329366/can-not-edit-rdl-report-2005-defination-in-vs-2008)

2. I can see a match for the code in the link below as well where the
   solution seems to be working for them:

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/28409-ReportViewer-with-multiple-dataset-report.aspx

At this point I have run out of solutions and need help.

### **Edit:**

What caused the issue in the first place?

In order to extend the problem for additional datasets, I had copied the table in my RDL designer. The designer seems to change the `<rd:TypeName>` tag to `<TypeName>`.

At this point I am really grateful for StackOverflow for providing this platform for me to post my problems and to @RezaAghaei, who in multiple occasions has gone that extra mile to look at all the details of a problems to give a solution in times of need.

Comment: It would be better to share your RDL(C) report somewhere. Then we can be sure about correct data source names. However The error message says something about error in report definition. The overall progress seems to be OK.

Comment: here is a sharable link form google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4zUWFlcSqrXWFpCaUwyMzNiLVU/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4zUWFlcSqrXNm5wVGJta29EQkE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As addressed in the exception, the element `Field` has invalid child element `TypeName`.

You should use `rd:TypeName` instead. For example:

```
<Field Name="id">
  <DataField>id</DataField>
  <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
</Field>
```

The problem is with second and next data sets, but first data set is OK.

Comment: Hi @rezaAghaei, thank you so much for helping us resolve this problem. I am really grateful that you took the time to look at the input file and help in root causing the problem and helping with the solution. Kudos to you (^_^)